# Orbeon form submit to third party system

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder, xbl

I have a requirement like [this](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/overview/accessing-data.html#1-send-data-on-submit), where I need to submit the same form data to third party system. I have tried to call send in save action as below.

```
then send(
    uri      = "http://localhost:8080/restcall/form",
    replace  = "none",
    method   = "post",
    content  = "xml",
    annotate = "id"
)
```

But the problem here is that the data format should be form parameter(Normal form submission). But using `send` I think that data will go in xml format.

- Please let me know how to submit data in form parameter
- How to submit specific hidden field(not all hidden field) to third party system using send

Comment: Did you try `method="get"`?

Comment: Here want to send data to external system using POST method, which will except data as form parameter. normal HTML form action submit with post method you can say. Please help how to submit data in required format. I want to submit it from orbeon form it self(not from server)

Comment: With Orbeon Forms data is always submitted from the Orbeon Forms server. It will never come directly from the browser. This said, you can try `method = "post"` and `serialization = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. This will look like a form post.

Comment: @avernet - There was some issue with SEND so as of now I have submitted data to third party system from server side(controller). But `I want to understand can we do it using HTTP Service & Action in form builder ?` , I can see there is no trigger point for successfully data save etc. in Action (Form builder)

Comment: Correct, right now Action & Service really are only to react to the form being loaded, values entered in fields, and clicks inside the form. If you want to define what happens when the buttons at the bottom of the form are used, you'll want to use the [buttons and processes](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/). Does this match what you were looking for?